# ¿Cómo determinar si una consulta arroja registros en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando bajo Sql Server 2016 y estoy haciendo un cursor que es un select a una tabla y trae un solo dato que es un `id`. Dentro del cursor se utiliza dicho `id` devuelto por el cursor como filtro en otro Select. Lo que no logro hacer es cómo verificar si este Select me trae registros. Cualquier apoyo estaré muy agradecido.

El contexto del problema es el siguiente:

1) Tengo una tabla A que tiene un solo campo y que corresponde a un id. En esta tabla están todos los id que deben clasificar para un proceso posterior. Cada id aparece sólo una vez en esta tabla.

2) Tengo las tablas X2015, X2016 y X2017 las cuales tienen la misma estructura de campos **id**, **tipo**, **grado** y **total**. Las tablas contienen la información de los año 2015, 2016 y 2017, respectivamente. Para cada **id** pueden haber 1 o varios **tipos**, pudiendo algunos **tipo** no existir para dicho **id**.  Para cada **tipo** pueden haber 1 o varios **grados**, pudiendo algunos **grados** no existir para dicho tipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3)Lo que se debe obtener a partir de las tablas del punto 1 y 2, es una tabla R, resumen con la información de las tres tablas del punto 2. Dicha tabla tiene los campos **id**, **tipo**, **grado**, **total2015**, **total2016** y **total2017**.

4)El escenario ideal es que recorriendo cada uno de los **id** de la tabla A, vaya a las tablas del punto 2 y obtenga para el par **tipo** y **grado**, el campo **total** del año de la tabla e inserte este total en la tabla R. Puede darse el caso que un id de la tabla A esté en las tres tablas anuales o sólo en dos o en caso extremo en una sola tabla. Lo mismo sucede con los tipos y grados; puede estar un tipo y grado el año 2015, pero el 2016 no se dio esa misma dupla y el 2017 volvió a darse, caso en el cual debe aparecer para dicho id, tipo y grado con un espacio en el campo total para el año 2016.

La pregunta que hice como título de este post surge a la luz de pensar que como estrategía podría declarar un cursor que fuera un select sobre la tabla A, la cual tiene todos los **id** que se deben considerar. Luego, abriendo el cursor, hacer una consulta a cada tabla de modo de ver si para el id que entrega el cursor, existe dicho id en las restantes tablas y en caso de que exista, insertar la información en la tabla R. Lo que consulto es cómo saber si cuando haga la consulta sobre la tabla anual, la consulta trae registros?

```
DECLARE RegistrosCursor CURSOR FOR  
select id
from TablaTemporal
order by id;
OPEN RegistrosCursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM RegistrosCursor  
INTO @id;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
            select a.id,a.tipo, a.grado, a.total
            from X2015
            where a.id=@id and 
                  a.tipo in(select tipo from enseñanza_grado where id=@i) 
                  and a.grado in(select grado from enseñanza_grado where id=@i)
```

Finalmente, no sé si la estrategia que estoy tomando es la mejor o más eficiente.

Quedo atento, gracias.

Comment: publica la estructura de tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: La funcion `EXISTS` se usa justamente para verificar eso, por ejemplo `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t)` devolvera true si hay registros y false si no los hay

Comment: Gracias por responder Sacha. El tema es que me parece que no me sirve, pues lo que necesito es hacer esa consulta, luego preguntar si la consulta trajo algún registro (que a lo sumo debería ser uno), en caso positivo debo incrementar un contador, hacer una inserción en la tabla R y luego hacer la misma consulta pero en la siguiente tabla 2016, pero antes de insertar, debo verificar si ya se hizo una inserción anterior, etc, etc, etc. Yo me imaginaba algo así como:


@test=exists(select * from t)


if(@test=0)

begin

    insert . . . 

end

Hay alguna instrucción para eso?

Answer (score 2):

Existe una variable global que te puede servir: [@@ROWCOUNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) .

Esta almacena cuantos registros regreso la última consulta ejecutada, en tu caso podrías hacer esta validación después del SELECT que muestras:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 SELECT 'REGRESO VALORES', @@ROWCOUNT ELSE SELECT 'NO REGRESO NADA' ENDIF
```